# Enqueuing to device side queue in a loop

Tags: opencl

In my code I have **kernelA** and **kernelB**. **kernelB** depends on **kernelA** results. I am iterating over this kernels tousand of times and each iteration depends on the results from the previous iteration.

The host side enqueue code snipped is like this:

```
for(int x = 0; x < iterations; ++x)
{
    queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernelA, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(3*256, 1), cl::NDRange(256, 1));
    queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernelB, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(256, 1), cl::NDRange(256, 1));
}
queue.finish();
```

The above code is working perfectly fine.

---

Now I want to port the above code to use device side enqueue and I'm facing issues on AMD GPU. The kernel code:

```
__attribute__((reqd_work_group_size(256, 1, 1)))
__kernel void kernelA(...){}

__attribute__((reqd_work_group_size(256, 1, 1)))
__kernel void kernelB(...){}

__attribute__((reqd_work_group_size(1, 1, 1)))
__kernel void kernelLauncher(...)
{
    queue_t default_queue = get_default_queue();
    clk_event_t ev1, ev2;

    for (int x = 0; x < iterations; ++x)
    {
        void(^fnKernelA)(void) = ^{ kernelA(
        ... // kernel params come here
            ); };

        if (x == 0)
        {
            enqueue_kernel(default_queue,
                CLK_ENQUEUE_FLAGS_NO_WAIT,
                ndrange_1D(3 * 256, 256),
                0, NULL, &ev1,
                fnKernelA);
        }
        else
        {
            enqueue_kernel(default_queue,
                CLK_ENQUEUE_FLAGS_NO_WAIT,
                ndrange_1D(3 * 256, 256),
                1, &ev2, &ev1, // ev2 sets dependency on kernelB here
                fnKernelA);
        }

        void(^fnKernelB)(void) = ^{ kernelB(
        ... // kernel params come here
            ); };

        enqueue_kernel(default_queue,
            CLK_ENQUEUE_FLAGS_NO_WAIT,
            ndrange_1D(256, 256),
            1, &ev1, &ev2,  // ev1 sets dependency on kernelA here
            fnKernelB);
    }
}
```

The host code:

```
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernelLauncher, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(1, 1), cl::NDRange(1, 1));
```

The issue is that the results returned from the kernel when run on AMD GPU are wrong. Sometimes kernel also hangs which may indicate that there is probably something wrong with kernel synchronization. The same code works fine on Intel CPU, not sure if that is a luck or there is something wrong with synchronization points in the kernel.

---

**Update:** `enqueue_kernel` is failing on 1025th enqueue command with error `-1`. I tried to get more detailed error (added `-g` during build) but to no avail. I increased the device queue size to maximum but that didn't change anything (still failing on 1025th enqueue command). Removing content of `kernelA` and `kernelB` didn't change anything either. Any thoughts?

Comment: In your first code snippet (enqueuing from the host), the work-group size for kernelA is set to `3*256`. In the second snipped (enqueuing from the device), the work-group size of kernelA is set to `256`? Are these supposed to be the same?

Comment: @jprice `kernelA` and `kernelB` for both version is exactly the same. `kernelA` is launched as 3 workgroups of 256 work items in both cases. Note that kernel side enqueue is set to `ndrange_1D(3 * 256, 256)`.

Comment: OK, but the code for your host enqueue at the top of your question launches one work-group of `3*256` work-items for `kernelA`, instead of  `3` work-groups of `256` work-items.

Comment: @jprice, yep, you are right, that was just a typo which I made when preparing the snipped, sorry about that.

Comment: Fair enough. Can't see anything else wrong with the code. Does it produce correct results if you just run a single iteration? Have you tried checking whether the `enqueue_kernel` functions are always returning `CLK_SUCCESS`?

Comment: @jprice Haven't tried single iteration yet as it's time consuming - need to prepare the data set with more complicated data for the first iteration. Haven't checked `enqueue_kernel` ret results yet too as on AMD OpenCL2.0 `printf` is crashing the kernel at build time, will need to do this same way as the old days when `printf` was not available. Anyway, thanks for confirming the code looks OK.

Comment: One last thought would to be to make sure you are releasing the event objects - this doesn't happen automatically, and you may be hitting some hardware limit. Otherwise, this may be worth a bug report to AMD.

Comment: This approach does not enter in the normal "use case" for in-kernel queueing. The normal case for these kind of actions is when you want to queue more kernels based on the result of previous kernels, and you don't want to collect data, wake the CPU just to check a single boolean. What you are doing is just queuing, and for that task CPU will surely be faster. Unless you are planing to extend this later on.

Comment: @DarkZeros, yes it will be extended later on but first I need to get simple case working.

Answer (score 0):

Answering an old question to hopefully save someone time in the future. If you query `CL_DEVICE_MAX_ON_DEVICE_EVENTS` on your device it will return 1024. That is the max number of events you can queue "on device". That is why it is failing on the 1025 queue. If you run your OpenCL code on a different GPU (like Intel) you may be lucky enough to get a real error code back which will be `CLK_DEVICE_QUEUE_FULL` or -161. AMD ignores the `-g` option and doesn't ever seem to give anything back but -1 on a failed on-device enqueue.